# Rails / RSpec: Using :assigns in an observer spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, observers

I'm logging the changes to a model to use in an activity feed. I have an observer that does this (activerecord dirty):

```
def before_update(derp)
  @changes = derp.changes
end
```

This abstracts this functionality out of the controller. I want to test this using rspec, so I have this:

```
it "assigns derp.changes to @changes" do
  derp.attribute = 5
  @observer.before_update(derp)
  expect(assigns(:changes)).to eq(derp.changes)
end
```

I'm getting this error: undefined method `assigns' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::DerpObserver::BeforeUpdate:0x007fc6e24eb7f8

How can I use assigns in an observer spec? Or, is there another way that I could test that @changes got assigned?

Answer (score 0):

instance_variable_get is what I was looking for.

http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_get

```
expect(@observer.instance_variable_get(:@changes)).to eq(derp.changes)
```